# Piping Multiple stdouts to Python program?

Tags: linux, pipe, fifo

I have a program that prints in stdout and I'd like multiple instances of it where each instance's stdout is piped to a sed and then the result(of three such sed) piped to a python program. I'm doing this

```
rtl_power -f 430M:434M:3.2M -g 30 -i 2 | sed -i '/2024-03-25/a \ dongle1' | python calc.py
```

and this works for one instance but now I am going to have 3 instances like

```
rtl_power -f 430M:434M:3.2M -g 30 -i 2 | sed -i '/2024-03-25/a \ dongle1' 
rtl_power -f 430M:434M:3.2M -g 30 -i 2 | sed -i '/2024-03-25/a \ dongle2' 
rtl_power -f 430M:434M:3.2M -g 30 -i 2 | sed -i '/2024-03-25/a \ dongle3'
```

and I'd want all of them piped to the same instance of `calc.py` (at the same time) so I could do some calculations. PS FIFO and writing to files is not an option because I want the calculations done in real time, also  `rtl_power` has streaming output

**EDIT:**

**Console tab 1:**

```
rtl_power -f 430M:434M:3.2M -g 30 -i 2 | sed -u '/2020-03-26/a \ dongle1' > /home/username/gatewayx
```

**Console tab 2:**

```
python /home/username/do.py < /home/username/gatewayx
```

*output*

```
2
device dongle1 strength -29.04

2020-03-26, 13:49:38, 430000000, 433200000, 3200000.00, 186, -29.04, -29.04
8
2
device dongle1 strength -29.04

2020-03-26, 13:49:40, 430000000, 433200000, 3200000.00, 295, -29.04, -29.04
8
2
device dongle1 strength -29.04

2020-03-26, 13:49:42, 430000000, 433200000, 3200000.00, 302, -29.04, -29.04
8
2
device dongle1 strength -29.04

2020-03-26, 13:49:44, 430000000, 433200000, 3200000.00, 303, -29.04, -29.04
8
2
device dongle1 strength -29.03

2020-03-26, 13:49:46, 430000000, 433200000, 3200000.00, 295, -29.03, -29.03
```

*(Output stops at this point)*

*python script only for reference:*

```
import time
import datetime
import sys

def printthis(Var):
    print Var
while True:
    donglename="emptry"
    dbs="emptry"
    line=sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        continue
    conts=line.split(' ')   
    ll=len(conts)
    print(ll)
    if len(conts)==8:
        #donglename=conts[8]
        #donglename=donglename.replace('\n','')
        dbs=conts[7]
        dbs=dbs.replace(',','')

    line2=sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line2:
        continue
    conts2=line2.split(' ') 
    ll2=len(conts2)
    print(ll2)
    if len(conts2)==2:
        donglename=conts2[1]
        donglename=donglename.replace('\n','')
        #dbs=conts[7]
        #dbs=dbs.replace(',','')

    print("device "+donglename+" strength "+dbs)


    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't FIFO be an option? How is a FIFO any less "real time" than a pipe, which is also essentially a FIFO?

Comment: Because I'll have to make those changes(reading from FIFO) in the C program(rtl_power) and I don't want to be messing with it's source code(going to github, cloning the source code, making changes, resolving dependencies and then rebuilding from scratch)

Comment: But why would you need to make those changes? `python calc.py < some_fifo` and `rtl_power ... | sed -i ... > some_fifo`.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but doesnt ```<``` rewrite while ```<<``` is the operator i should be using because that will append(given id want the whole streaming data), secondly both of these operators ```<``` and ```<<<``` are IO blocking so two instances of rtl_power would be unable to write to ```some_fifo``` at the same time, no?
EDIT: previously I used the ```mkfifo``` in pytho nfor that task while the fstream in cpp for this purpose for interprocess communications(also relatively new to the whole linux environment so forgive me if my questions strike as too stupid)

Comment: As long as something is reading from the fifo, it shouldn't block writing. Why didn't you just test it out?

Comment: It does seem to work but is very unreliable. Apparently for some reason after reading 2-3 lines it crashes the other program(rtl_power) while an underlying process necessary for rtl_power keeps running(rtl_sdr) and so the only way to restart rtl_power is then ejecting and reinserting the dongle. I remember having similar problems with fifo before and gave up on it. The problems usually arise because it's like to access the fifo from one end it has to be already opened at the other end and so timing of both programs is very crucial(or something along the lines of that).

Comment: Maybe add what exactly you tried to the post.